# which table in ODI 10g stores details about all the sessions launched

Tags: oracle10g, oracle-data-integrator

Can anyone help me know which table in ODI 10g stores details about all the sessions launched.

Answer (score 0):

Odi Stores all the data in SNP_Session table on Work Repo.

[image]